# The parameterized query '(@FirstName nvarchar(4000))select * from tblEm where FirstName=@' expects the parameter '@FirstName', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, asp.net-ajax

I am getting above exception while executing the code attached. Please help. I am successfully getting posted data from ajax call but unable perform the select operation using ado.net. I am attaching controller code with this question.attached image [image]

### Controller code:-

```
public ActionResult notCk_Pk(String FirstName,String LastName,int? Salary,String Gender)
        {

            List<Counting> l = new List<Counting>();
            //String FirstName = FirstName;
            //String LastName = LastName;
            //int Salary = Salary;
            //String Gender = Gender;

                string query = "select * from tblEm where FirstName=@FirstName";
                string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeContext"].ConnectionString;
                SqlDataAdapter da;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Srivatsava; integrated security=SSPI"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName",FirstName);
                        //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(n.FirstName))
                        //{
                        //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", DBNull.Value);
                        //}
                        connection.Open();
                        Object o=cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        if (o != null)
                        {
                            string city = o.ToString(); 
                        }
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, ConnectionString);
                da.Fill(ds);
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    l.Add(new Counting() { FirstNamecount = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), LastNamecount = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]), Salary = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]), Gendercount = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]) });
                }



            var todoListsResults = l.Select(
                  a => new
                  {

                      a.FirstNamecount,
                      a.LastNamecount,
                      a.Salary,
                      a.Gendercount

                  });

            var jsonData = new
            {
                //   total = totalPages,
                // page,
                //records = totalRecords,
                rows = todoListsResults
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);




        }
```

Comment: but my code struck here in this statement cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention,I replaced ExecuteScalar with ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: That's even worse - `ExecuteNonQuery()` is **only** intended for operations like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` that **do not** return any data- you definitely want to return data.

Comment: Ok.Actually I am posting data with ajax call to the above controller method.Is that the reason for this error?

Comment: See my response - I tried to fix all the issues you had

Comment: Thanks Marc for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **fill** a `DataTable` (absolutely no need to use a `DataSet`, if you only get a single table, and no relations) - then use this code:

```
public ActionResult notCk_Pk(String FirstName, String LastName, int? Salary, String Gender)
{
    List<Counting> l = new List<Counting>();

    string query = "select * from tblEm where FirstName = @FirstName";
    string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeContext"].ConnectionString;

    -- set up and connection and command in "using"        
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        -- define parameter - don't use "AddWithValue"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = FirstName;

        -- define data adapter and use the *existing* "cmd"   
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        -- fill a DataTable since you only get data from a single table
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            l.Add(new Counting() { FirstNamecount = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), 
                                   LastNamecount = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]), 
                                   Salary = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]), 
                                   Gendercount = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]) 
                                 });
        }
    }

    var todoListsResults = l.Select(
      a => new
      {

          a.FirstNamecount,
          a.LastNamecount,
          a.Salary,
          a.Gendercount

      });

    var jsonData = new
        {
            rows = todoListsResults
        };

    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Points I've improved:

- use the `ConnectionString`, if you fetch it - don't fetch the connection string from config, and then use a hard-coded string instead....
- removed the unnecessary, pointless `.ExecuteNonQuery()` or `.ExecuteScalar()` calls
- create the `SqlDataAdapter` with the pre-existing `SqlCommand cmd` to use the connection and parameters that command has already set up !
- define the parameter with a `.Add()` call - **not** `.AddWithValues()` (check out this article [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) as to **why** - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...)

Comment: I declared DataSet for instance ds. I am getting error Must declare the scalar variable "@FirstName" now.

Comment: @Baji: as I said, you **don't need** a `DataSet` - a single `DataTable` will do and is just as good. No point in having unnecessary overhead.....

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, but it is pointing error in line da.fill(ds).

Comment: Same error Must declare the scalar variable "@FirstName".

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know what's wrong - the code works **just fine** on my test machine. Are you really using my code unchanged, or did you tweak it?

Comment: I am using the modified code but same error as per description